# Complejidad algoritmica - Caso y notación

Tags: python, python-3.x, complejidad

Tengo el siguiente algoritmo y se me pide estudiar la complejidad algorítmica en el peor caso. El código es:

```
def sort_me(array):
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(array) - 1):
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
                swapped = True
```

Según entiendo del código, básicamente lo que hace es en función del array que se le pase y comparando los valores dentro de él intercambia las posiciones o no. Así pues, si le paso el `array = [4,2,5,3]` el resultado seria `array = [2,4,3,5]`. Ahora viene la discusión, en mi opinión este algoritmo en el peor caso es O(n^2) donde n es el numero de items que tienen que ser tratados ya que **potencialmente** podria ser que hubieramos de hacer un loop en todo el array cada vez que llegamos a un nuevo elemento.

Otro tema seria la notación a usar para definir la función de complejidad. Según tengo entendido se usa:

- O (grande):  La función queda definida únicamente por encima.
- 0 (theta): La función queda definida por un límite superior y otro inferior.

En este caso pues solo veo el límite superior, en este sentido la notación a usar seria O(n)=n con límite superior en O(n)=n^2?

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que tu función está incompleta. Parece que falta una llamada recursiva en alguna parte. Asi como esta sólo hace una pasada por la lista (sería entonces O(n)).

Comment: Tienes razón. Habia leido mal el codigo!

Comment: No hace falta una llamada recursiva para lograr O(n^2). Con el _simple_ `while`/`for` que tiene este algoritmo, en el peor de los casos, recorrerá n - 1 veces la lista completa de n elementos, lo cual nos da n(n -1), que yo resumiría como n^2, solo por simplicidad de notación. Sobre la forma de escribirlo, lo que yo uso es poner la complejidad entre el paréntesis, sin signo de igual, con lo cual, para ser exactos, sería O(n(n-1)) o simplemente O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Has evaluado mal el resultado del código.

Si se le pasa el array `[4,2,5,3]` va a dejarlo como `[2,3,4,5]`

Mi análisis:

Con el `while`/`for` que tiene este algoritmo, en el peor de los casos, recorrerá n - 1 veces la lista completa de n elementos, lo cual nos da n(n -1), que yo resumiría como n^2, solo por simplicidad de notación.

Sobre la forma de escribirlo, lo que yo uso es poner la complejidad entre el paréntesis, sin signo de igual, con lo cual, para ser exactos, sería **O(n(n-1))** o simplemente **O(n^2)** u **O(n²)**.

Es fácil comprobarlo, he modificado un poco el código para que hable por si mismo:

```
def sort_me(array):
    contador = 0
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(array) - 1):
            contador += 1
            if array[i] > array[i + 1]:
                array[i], array[i + 1] = array[i + 1], array[i]
                swapped = True

    print('n:', len(array), ' => ', contador, ' repeticiones')
    return array


print(sort_me([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
print(sort_me([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(sort_me([2, 1, 5, 3, 4]))
print(sort_me([4, 2, 5, 3]))
```

La salida es:

```
n: 5  =>  20  repeticiones
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n: 5  =>  4  repeticiones
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n: 5  =>  8  repeticiones
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n: 4  =>  9  repeticiones
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Como puedes observar, el peor caso se da cuando se pasa un arreglo en orden inverso, lo cual hace que el algoritmo tenga que recorrerlo n-1 veces.